# How to access variables in different class from other class

Tags: c++, c++11

x cannot be static

I'd like to have

```
class A{
  static std::vector<C> vec_ca;
public:
  int x = 6;
`};
class B{
 std::vector<C> vec_cb;
public:
 int x = 7;
};
class C
{
  void foo(){
  int  k = x;
  }
};
```

And k will be set depending of it class: if k in vec_ca k = 6; if k in vec_cb k = 7. Is it possible to be done?

Comment: You can use getter and setter methods.

Comment: Why you dont want x as static?

Comment: If you dont want it as static then you have to create object for respective class

Comment: In my project x will be different in different instances of A

Comment: @aLLex Does my answer support your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways. You can use getter and setter methods like so:

```
class B{
 std::vector<C> vec_cb;
public:
  int get_x(){return x;}
private:
  int x = 7;
};
```

and call `get_x` from the other class. And one other way to accomplish this is using friend classes. So you can do:

```
class B{
 std::vector<C> vec_cb;
 friend class A;
private:
  int x = 7;
};
```

Comment: Why return value of class should be reference?

Comment: Your program as error. Spot the error. Lol

Comment: @vinothcse2000 what? sorry i just came back from lunch , oh sorry ... my fault i thought he actually wanted to change the variable.. Changed

Comment: Semicolon was missed earlier for friend class.. cool

Comment: To call get_x I need to pass instance of A to C, right?

Comment: @aLLex , yes.. indeed